# Are there any missable sidequests?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Are all sidequests available until the end of the game or will some be locked off or automatically failed if I pass a storyline point?

Comment: The only ones I am not sure about are shrine quests, and whether if you've already discovered the shrine the NPC who tells you how to find it will still give it you. However, no shrine quests have rewards apart from the shrine itself, so it'd only matter if you were specifically doing an 'All Quests' run.

Comment: @SGR: I just got (and insta-completed) The Eye of the Sandstorm shrine quest for a shrine I'd already been to, so it looks like you can still get shrine quests after you've beaten the corresponding shrine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Quests do not expire in that fashion. The most strict quests get is that some can only be done at night.

Comment: Any source you can quote on that or personal experience?

Comment: This is personal experience, but I have done a fair number of quests, including ones with descriptions that make them seem urgent. Given that there isn't anything in the game that spans days (only day/night, but not "over the course of a week, do this") I'm coming to this conclusion. I also don't think it's possible to fail quests, period, as a failure condition often results in an immediate restart.

Answer (score 3):

I thought there were some miss-able ones but they ended up working out in the end. Some missions just have some prerequisites before they can trigger.

Answer (score 2):

All quests can be completed in any order. But I know that some quests if not correctly completed won't show up on your side quest completion list. I have two that I can't re-initiate or complete.